# Determinant of Gram matrix is non-zero, but vectors are not linearly independent

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, jordan-normal-form

From Wikipedia:

> a set of vectors is linearly independent if and only if the Gram determinant (the determinant of the Gram matrix) is non-zero.

But consider the matrix M:

```
  5   4   2   1
  0   1  -1  -1
 -1  -1   3   0
  1   1  -1   2
```

The Gram matrix G is:

```
 27  22   6  7
 22  19   3  5
  6   3  15  1
  7   5   1  6
```

And the determinant of G is 1024.  The eigenvalues of M are:

```
4, 4, 1, 2
```

The eigenvectors of M are:

```
 -0.58   0.58  -0.71  -0.58
  0.0   -0.0    0.71   0.58
  0.58  -0.58   0.0    0.0
 -0.58   0.58   0.0   -0.58
```

And the rank of this eigenvector matrix is 3, not 4, so... the vectors are not linearly independent.  Am I missing something obvious here?  Thanks.

Comment: If a matrix is not diagonalizable, it does not necessarily mean that it is singular. E.g., Matlab often computes a linearly dependent eigenvector matrix in such a case.

Comment: All of the eigenvalues of $M$ are non zero, so $M$ is non-singular, which is to say it's columns are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the matrix

```
1  1
0  1
```

It's got one eigenvector,

```
0
1
```

so its eigenvector matrix, as reported by matlab, will be

```
0  0
1  1
```

Its eigenvalues are 1 and 1. But it's got rank 2, even though the eignevector matrix has rank 1. So what you're missing is a clear understanding of what matlab returns when it computes an eigenvector matrix.